# Android setText from custom xml or html

Tags: android, xml

I'm not sure but is it possible to set text in android from a custom xml or html?

example: I have text.xml or text.html which contains

```
<item>
<id>1</id>
<question>how r u?</question>
<answer>fine</answer>
<answer right>good</answer>
<answer>bad</answer>
<answer>not in mood</answer>
</item>
```

now in my activity, I have 5 textviews. the first one gets to set as the qustions so it will be"how r u?" .. and the other four will be "fine", "good", "bad", and "not in mood".
Now when I click on "good" because in the file it was `<answer right>` so I get to another activity using intent and when I click on rest of answers they take me to another specific activity too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the XmlParser to parse the xml files and set the text in the TextView

Check this link

[Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

[Parsing XML Using DOM Parser from Assets](http://android-developersspott.blogspot.in/2012/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-parser-from.html)

Comment: yes it is..check the link that i've provided..it has the example.

Comment: Umm this link takes from the net .. I'm looking for an xml which is in the project it self, same method?